# Scroll Position Update on Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-waypoints, onscroll

I am using the following code below, which is working just fine. However when I view it on my mobile phone the triggers aren't run until scrolling stops, not when it reaches that point. Is there a way to report the scroll position while you scroll for mobile devices? instead of when it stops.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
 element: document.getElementById('trigger-1'),
  handler: function(direction) {
   console.log(direction);
   if(direction == "down"){
    $(".sign-up-absolute").css("position","fixed");
    $(".sign-up-absolute").css("top","25%");
   }
    else{
    $(".sign-up-absolute").css("position","absolute");
    $(".sign-up-absolute").css("top","150px");
   }
  }
 });

 var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('trigger-2'),
    handler: function(direction) {
      if(direction == "up"){
        $(".sign-up-absolute").css("position","fixed");
        $(".sign-up-absolute").css("top","25%");
       }
       else{
        $(".sign-up-absolute").css("position","absolute");
        $(".sign-up-absolute").css("top","150px");
        }
      }   
  });
```